# ruby - class instantiation and initialization (initialize is not called?)

Tags: ruby, base-class

```
class Test

  def initialize 
    puts 'initializing test'
  end

end

class TestB < Test

end

something = Class.new(Test)
```

In the above, the superclass initialize method is not called. If I do

```
something = TestB.new
```

it is called.

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading the documentation, Class.new(Test) yields a derived class object which has Test as its superclass.

You need to call new on that result to get the printout.

```
TestA = Class.new(Test)
something_else = TestA.new
```